# quicksort gets rid of duplicate values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I tried to write some code to get quicksort running in javascript, but the final array is returned without duplicates (if it originally had some)

```
function quickSort(array) {
  if (array.length <= 1) return array;
  var pivot = array[0];

var left = quickSort(array.filter(item =>item < pivot));
var right = quickSort(array.filter(item =>item > pivot));

//console.log('left ',left);
//console.log("right ",right);

  return [...left,pivot,...right];
}

console.log(quickSort([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2])); // <- this returns [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: You can use this to learn and see one implementation in JS: https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2012/11/27/computer-science-in-javascript-quicksort/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're filtering by only keeping items that are strictly lower (`<`) or strictly higher (`>`) than your pivot.

You can fix this by changing one of your conditions to `<=` instead of `<` (or `>=` instead of `>`). Note that when you do that, you must make sure that the pivot element is taken out of the array.

So in this line:

```
var left = quickSort(array.filter(item =>item < pivot));
```

We can take the pivot out by calling `array.slice(1)` (note that this isn't very efficient, see modified solution at the end). Then we change the condition to `<=`, and the final code becomes:

```
function quickSort(array) {
  if (array.length <= 1) return array;
  var pivot = array[0];

  var left = quickSort(array.slice(1).filter(item =>item <= pivot));
  var right = quickSort(array.filter(item =>item > pivot));

//console.log('left ',left);
//console.log("right ",right);

  return [...left,pivot,...right];
}

console.log(quickSort([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2])); // [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

A more elegant solution would be to remove the pivot from the array before filtering it. Instead of using slice, you can use `shift()` to remove the first item from an array. Modified solution becomes:

```
function quickSort(array) {
  if (array.length <= 1) return array;
  var pivot = array[0];
  // Remove first element
  array.shift()

  var left = quickSort(array.filter(item =>item <= pivot));
  var right = quickSort(array.filter(item =>item > pivot));

  return [...left,pivot,...right];
}

console.log(quickSort([5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2])); // [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```